# CSS/Bootstrap v3 - Align Search button and Input field (Bootstrap 3 in Drupal)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

Using Bootstrap v3 within Drupal v7.6x and the Search API module (and Search Page) I have tried to align the Search button with the Input field yet neither will align horizontally. Maybe I can't see the 'wood for the trees' but I can't seem to get it to fix using CSS in an override.css.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong or missing out on?
Thank you in advance.
Paul B

Attached: image of input form item and CSS taken from Chrome/Firefox Web Inspector tool.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe not the correct one but not that suits me today until I can learn more about css.
What I did was in my css I created a line in my overrides.css and added the following css line:

```
#search-api-page-search-form div {
display: flex;
margin-bottom: 0px
```

}

being the targeted search box being used. The problem I had was that the fields were in the 'div' hence the div at the end of the code. At least I fixed, now I can continue to build on it next.

If anyone has any enhanced answers, please feel free to suggest and correct my code.